# how to compare 2 elements of different arrays?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have two arrays, one is containers and the other are the pieces and every node has its name, for example "circle blue piece" and "circle blue container", but there are squares, hexagones, triangles, stars.

I want that when I drag a piece into a container, it compares if it match then it can be placed there. I have it hardcoded like this:

```
if firstBody.node?.name == "Container_Circle_Blue" && secondBody.node?.name == figure_name_cb {
    print("Contact detected")
    containerSprite[0].block.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Circle_Blue_Filled")
    //print("Contact happened between square 1 and square 2")
    circle_blue.isHidden = true
    circle_blue.physicsBody = nil
    arraySprites.remove(at: index)
    
}else{
    
    circle_blue.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / -4, y: self.frame.size.width / 2)
}
```

but it is a condition for every piece, and I had to name every piece like its container, and assign the piece to a position, but I want to randomize the board of containers every time the app starts, so it is not a very good practice and the code is messy and very long.

Comment: I would make an enumeration per attribute (e.g. color, shape), and then a struct that holds a value of each of those enumerations. Then, your pieces will have a value of this structure which defines their type, and the containers will define a value of this structure which defines the type they accept. They could even have an array of multiple instances, in case they accept multiple types

Comment: I am not following what you are trying to do here? You are doing this in the did contact method, so why not just make a different `categoryBitMask` flag per container (You can have up to 32) and avoid checking by name entirely